# How to Send json configuration file as part of pyspark job on dataproc?

Tags: pyspark, etl

I want to query multiple tables from sql server and store into gcs bucket. I have all the information required like db_name, table_name, destination location in json file. How will I use this json configuration file to achieve my task.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options that you can use to achieve this.

1. If your table names are not changing and remains constant then you can hardcode that at one place in the code without using the configuration file.
2. If you want to use the configuration file then you could move or store your configuration file at specific location on HDFS,S3 or GCS bucket before your spark job runs using api call or any other options. Now when you want to run your pyspark job you can pass the path of the file as parameter to the job and your job would read the file from that location and get the details of db_name, table_name, destination location and you can use it as you want. You would have to read the json file using spark and get the individual value and use it.